# How to say my curiosity regarding why ABC has not been done has led me to study XYZ

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is there a better way to say the following?

> My curiosity regarding why one of the world's largest democracies has
>   not been able to resolve these issues has led me to study economics.

Comment: I'd more likely say "my curiosity as to why one of the world's largest democracies has not been able to resolve these issues has led me to study Economics".

Comment: I'd probably go with: "I started studying economics because I was curious why one of the world's largest democracies has been unable to resolve these issues."

Answer (score -1):

This sentence is in passive voice.  It would be better in active voice.  Also, "studying economics" is the key part of the sentence and so would be better at the beginning of the sentence.  Personally, I think "about" would be a better word that "regarding".  These three changes lead to:

*I was lead to study economics because of my curiosity about why one of the world's largest democracies has not been able to resolve these issues.*

Comment: Isn't it still in the passive voice? If you edit to active, I'll upvote. (Agree regarding regarding.)

Comment: The subject is "I", so I would call this sentence active voice.  However, I can see than there are ways to make it more active.  For example:  "I studied economics because..."  I avoided this because it makes a slight change to the emphasis of the sentence.

Comment: The original sentence in the question is not in the passive voice—all verbal forms in it are active voice. Ironically, your version **is** in the passive voice. The subject being _I_ has no bearing whatsoever on whether the verbal phrase is active or passive.